# Can shooting someone in the forehead from point blank range not kill him?

Tags: mortality, weapons

I was reading Mathew Reilly's [Scarecrow and the Army of Thieves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarecrow_and_the_Army_of_Thieves). In the book, a guy is shot in the forehead, but miraculously he does not die because his forehead is that strong.

Is it true, can a shot like that not kill?

Comment: Related Question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/can-a-metal-plate-in-the-head-stop-a-bullet

Comment: What we've seen in questions like these is: depends on the gun, depends on the bullet.

Comment: No, there is no metal plate in his head, just bone, as for the gun please w8

Comment: There has been lots of discussion about whether [claims from fictional stories](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/random-claims-from-fantasy-stories-and-movies) are notable. I am not familiar with the book or author. Is it reasonable to say he expected his readers to believe the claim that this was possible in real life?

Comment: Hmm, i have no idea, if he expected the readers to believe that, it's just something that happens and turns the plot of the story.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Reilly's books often have his characters performing implausible feats of skill, but this is a different sort of claim.

Comment: He did tell that, you know, unlike the maghook this might be real.

Comment: From how far away is he shot? Guns don't reach the infinite - the farer you're away, the less power the projectile has. Depending on the gun and amunition, the distance, where your chance to survive increases, differs. Of course, in such a distance you can only be hit by luck.

Comment: @userunknown point blank, gun's muzzle at forehead.

Comment: [Phineas Gage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_Gage) would probably say you can stand even more than a bullet...

Comment: Not sure that a claim from a work of fiction is appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image: Gabrielle Giffords] <sup>[Source](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748703667904576072190494009886.html)</sup>

Former Arizona Rep. **[Gabrielle Giffords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabrielle_Giffords#Attempted_assassination) was shot in the head on January 8, 2011. She survived.**

From **[The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/15/us/15medical.html?pagewanted=2&_r=1)** (January 14, 2011):

> Ms. Giffords needed surgery immediately. She had skull fractures, dead
>   brain tissue that had to be removed, and increasing pressure from
>   swelling that could further damage her brain as it expanded and
>   pressed against her skull. In addition, her eye sockets had fractures.
>
> **The bullet had passed through her skull. Fortunately, it had not
>   severed arteries or veins.**
>   
> ...

[image: Giffords - 2012] <sup>[Gabrielle Giffords on January 2012](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/picturegalleries/picturesoftheday/9038139/Pictures-of-the-day-25-January-2012.html?image=24)</sup>

**More:**

- [Nature - Anatomy of a brain injury](http://www.nature.com/news/2011/110111/full/news.2011.9.html)
- [WebMD - Gabrielle Giffords' Brain Injury](http://www.webmd.com/brain/news/20110109/gabrielle-giffords-brain-injury-faq)
- [Scientific American - A Key Series of Events Helped Giffords Survive a Gunshot Wound to the Head](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=gabrielle-giffords-gunshot-survival)

Comment: There's also this story about an American copper getting shot in the head and surviving http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2094764/Kevin-Brennan-Miracle-NYPD-cop-survives-shot-head.html

Comment: A family memember of mine is a neuro-surgeon and she is often performing emergency operations on gunshot victims. She operates on point-blank gunshot trauma maybe once a month. Next time I see her I will have to ask her what the survival rate is.

Comment: @MarkHenderson: Did you ask her? :D

Comment: @omega - no, I've seen her a bunch of times since then and I totally forgot to ask. She doesn't do much trauma any more as she now does private patients for pain relief neuro surgery.

Comment: Don't forget the story of Phineas Gage. A railroad pike right through the eye socket. Not a bullet per se, but still...

Comment: I know this answer has been accepted, but the question specifically asked about the possibility of the skull resisting penetration - *this* answer instead deals with someone who had a bullet go *right through* her skull.

Answer (score 12):

The publication *[Missile Wounds of the Head and Neck](http://books.google.com/books?id=O7GzmPy6uqEC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=handgun%20%22head%20wounds%22%20%22wound%20ballistics%22&source=web&ots=cJ_lCOEq45&sig=fb_MEJh0uUynupkDjpEYpSB_huQ#PPA45,M1)* states the following:

> If a bullet is fired straight-on into the head, bullet deflection is unlikely; however, if the bullet is fired at an angle or hits a curved portion of the skull, deflection will usually result. In some cases, the bullet will form a wound track as it follows the curved bone, and may even exit without perforating the skull.

**Therefore, is it possible?  Yes.  Is it likely?  No.**

Comment: Exactly my thought.  Light bullets have a very definite possibility of bouncing off if they don't come straight in.  It's more of an issue for suicides, though.

Comment: It's really hard to shoot yourself in the **forehead**.  Most people go for the temple, which has much weaker protections.